# Does WIC or DirectComposition replace GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+, wic, direct-composition

I have a project that might involve some basic server side image creation (scaling, transforming, some text composting). In the past I've used GDI+ to do similar things, but [Microsoft labels that as Legacy Graphics now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663279.aspx) and lists a few replacements such as *DirectComposition* and *Windows Imaging Component*.

I'm a little unclear of the distinction, so which of those (if any) is the best replacement for GDI+?

Comment: Sure, GDI+ is very old.  That they list WPF in the "legacy graphics" bracket is pretty funny.  WIC and DC are not direct replacements, you can't, say, draw a line with them.  Nor are they easily accessible from C# unless you target a Store app.

Answer (score 2):

[Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990.aspx) is the replacement for GDI+.